# TFTP boot file download aborted during PXE boot up

Tags: dhcp, pxe-boot, tftp

I'm using OpenDHCPServer together with OpenTFTPServer in order to try out network booting. My problem is after acquiring IP address client starts downloading the boot file and halts.

Message in TFTP log file being:

```
[20-Aug-15 14:35:32] Client 10.0.0.3:2070 c:\tftp\pxelinux.0, Client 10.0.0.3:2070, Error Code 0 at Client, TFTP Aborted
[20-Aug-15 14:35:32] Client 10.0.0.3:2071 c:\tftp\pxelinux.0, 19 Blocks Served
```

For what I found out a block in OpenTFTP is by default 512 bytes. The boot file's size should be 53 blocks. I tried passing a fake file of 1 block in hopes of some error quote but no luck there, client still just halts (well not really the cursor still blinks).

My DHCP configuration is:

```
[RANGE_SET]
DHCPRange=10.0.0.2-10.0.0.5
SubnetMask=255.255.255.0
BootFileName="pxelinux.0"
NextServer=10.0.0.1
```

The TFTP server has everything default except

```
[HOME]
C:\tftp\
```

During regular service both IP assigning and file transfer work.

---

EDIT

What the hell, now it transfered all 53 as I lowered maximum block size to 512. Apparently the comments in the server config are full of lies. Nevertheless, after that the client halts.

Awwww turns out it's the pxelinux.0 that makes the client halt. Grub4dos loaded without problems. My bad, lesson here is, don't cargo cult tutorials.

Answer (score -1):

If your client began transferring files only when you set  blocksize=512
then that tells me your client does not support `TFTP blocksize option RFC 2348` if that's the case your client's PXE firmware is ancient and surelly buggy. Please try upgrading the firmware before any new PXE booting attempt.